# Meteor stack traces stringified and printed on one line

Tags: meteor

All the server stack traces are printed on one line. It looks like they are stringified and only then printed. 
Example:

```
I20151215-23:18:57.623(0)? Exception while invoking method 'adminCheckAdmin' { stack: 'Error: When the modifier option is true, validation object must have at least one operator\n    at checkModifier (packages/aldeed_simple-schema/simple-schema-validation.js:271:1)\n    at doValidation1 (packages/aldeed_simple-schema/simple-schema-validation.js:321:1)\n    at [...]
I20151215-23:18:57.623(0)?   source: 'method' }
```

I am not sure how to debug and fix this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was `kadira:debug` package.
After uninstalling all stack traces are properly formatted.